# Android Activity & Timer Loop

Tags: android, timer, android-activity

I am writing an app that say has two activities A & B. A is a display page while B is a settings page.
In runtime, there is a timer loop running in A which keep on updating the display. And the settings in B affects some tasks in the timer loop.
I want it possible for users to switch from A to B in runtime and make changes in B, while the timer loop is still running in A and will response to the changes made in B.

Is it possible?
Or should I place the timer loop in somewhere else?
I'm new in Android & Java. Please kindly help. Thx.

Comment: You can only run one Activity at a time but you can easily create a "settings" Activity with the Preference (and PreferenceActivity) class.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried with the Preference class and it was great. But the same problem is bothering me. How do I make sure my timer is always running no matter which activity I am at?

Comment: You can extend the Application class and give it your timer. Application starts before the first Activity, Service, or BroadcastReceiver and doesn't finish until all of those are done.